# Facebook migration from api v2.3 to v2.4 - Rails omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth-facebook

I have some old app in Rails 4.0.0. Until 8th of Jul 2017 facebook registering works ok, but now v2.3 is deprecated and users can't register on my page.

Here is user.rb code:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)

    oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new('xxx', 'xxxx')
    new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info auth.credentials.token

    new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
    new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds

    user = where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first

    if !user.present?
      user = where(email: auth.info.email).first

      if user.present?
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.oauth_token = new_access_token
        user.oauth_expires_at = new_access_expires_at
        user.save!
      else
        user = User.new
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.profile.gender = 1
        user.confirmed_at = Time.now
        user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        user.fb_image_url = auth.info.image

        user.oauth_token = new_access_token
        user.oauth_expires_at = new_access_expires_at

        @str = user.fb_image_url.to_s
        @index = @str.index('type')
        @sliced = @str.slice(0, @index)
        @slices = @sliced + 'width=800&height=800'
        user.fb_image_url = @slices
        if auth.info.gender == 'female'
            user.fb_gender = 1
        elsif auth.fb_gender == 'male'
            user.fb_gender = 2
        end

      end

    end 

    user 

end
```

And here is /initializers/devise.rb :

```
require "omniauth-facebook"

  config.omniauth :facebook, 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 
    scope: 'email,public_profile', 
    info_fields: 'email', 
    client_options: {
    site: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4', authorize_url: "https://www.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/oauth"},
    token_params: { parse: :json }
```

Gemfile - `gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'`

What I need to change to make it work ? Right now after click "register by facebook" user is redirected to facebook, he login, accept permission and after redirect to my site - he is redirect to /users/sign_in - not like earlier to /users/sign_up to fill few more fields.

I stop making apps in Rails so do not know how to make it. Thanks for help

EDIT:

Ok, now it works but facebook do not return email so I need to add email field after redirect to my site. Why email is blank ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this in devise.rb:

config.omniauth :facebook, "KEY", "SECRET", scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, name'

Also check https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook for more info.

Comment: as You can see in my code there is : scope and info_fields